# Why does index.html load the css or js modules, does a request as if they were directories?

Tags: javascript, html, css, express

I'm writing a simple server with expressjs:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var api = require('./routes/main');    
var app = express();

app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use(logger('dev')); //Used to log HTTP requests
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //Used to automatically parse requests body
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/*', express.static('./public')); //serving static files under public folder

app.use(function(req,res){
  res.send("404");
});

var server = app.listen(8000, "0.0.0.0", function () {
   console.log('RAVE listening on port ' + server.address().port + 'hosting at ' + server.address().address);
});

module.exports = app;
```

in public directory there are index.htm, some css files and one js script, When index.html tries to load css or js scripts, it does through GET /path/file.css/ and loads a directory instead of file.css. Why??

index.html:

```
  <head>
  ....
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/view-style.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
```

console:

```
GET /stylesheets/view-style.css/ 200 8.979 ms - 10602
GET /js/main.js/ 200 8.598 ms - 10602
```

chrome sources:

[image: chromesources]

Comment: I solved, I do not know why, but in Chrome cache there were "main.js" directories, and so on. So when my html tried to load the files, Chrome forced him to use his cached files. I had to clean the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have already solved the problem . But just for future reference . 
We have something called cache-busting . Basically use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js?version=1"></script>
```

Whenever you change the file change the version number in  the code above